# Sudo does not work with Ansible AWX

Tags: ansible

I have set `sudo_user` in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`.

In my playbook I have set `remote_user`, `sudo_user` and `sudo:yes` (also tried `sudo:True`) on the same level as `hosts:`
I then use a role that does:

> shell: cp -f src /usr/local/bin/dest
>
> sudo: yes

and get

> stderr: cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/local/bin/dest': Permission denied

The credentials in AWX are set correctly - I am able to manually log in as the desired user on the remote machine and copy the file with sudo cp. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What's your sudo user? Your base playbook should look something like this:

```
# Base System: this is my base playbook
- name: Base Playbook
  hosts: all
  user: myuser
  sudo: True
```